# How to override content description for an Action Bar MenuItem?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-menu

I have an ActionBar for which I add a couple of MenuItems objects inside the Activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` method. But I need to override the content description for one of these items.

I've been thinking about defining the MenuItem in XML and setting up the actionViewClass attribute. And back in source code, call `MenuItem.getActionView()` for the MenuItem, just like described in http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html. That way I could call `setContentDescription()` on the View object it returns. But I would rather do that without using XML file.

Does anyone has any ideas besides using the XML option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out. Fortunately, I did not have to turn to the XML alternative. What I had to do was create a fresh View object, and [apply it as the MenuItem's actionView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(int)). The hard part was actually to style the view object as any ordinary `MenuItem` would look like for the current theme (if I added it without using actionView). Follows the snippet (assuming the name of my activity is `MyActivity`):

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Button buttonView = new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.actionButtonStyle);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            buttonView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Widget_ActionBar_Menu);
        } else {
            buttonView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Widget_ActionBar_Menu);
        }
        buttonView.setText(R.string.option_title); // button label
        buttonView.setContentDescription("Content description");
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MyActivity.this.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        });

        MenuItem item = menu.add(R.string.option_title);
        item.setActionView(buttonView);
        ...
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it recently for my app and the selected answer helped me, posting selected answer In Kotlin:

```
val profileIcon = ImageButton(context)
profileIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_profile)
profileIcon.background = null
profileIcon.contentDescription = "Profile"
val item: MenuItem = menu.add("Profile")
item.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
item.actionView = profileIcon
profileIcon.setOnClickListener {
    onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
```

Comment: Thank you, @karan-sharma